# NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats doesn't invoke the method

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

The timer never invokes the method. What am I doing wrong ? This is the code:

```
NSTimer *manualOverlayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideManual) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

method:

```
-(void)hideManual
```

thanks

Comment: how have you defined the 'hideManual' method?

Comment: it should have this signature: - (void) hideManual:(NSTimer *)aTimer;

Comment: @ObaidAbdulMaroof it should have just this signature `-(void)hideManual` and nothing else

Comment: @HamedRajabi: R u sure??? the documentation at apple's site says "The selector must correspond to a method that returns void and takes a single argument."...

Comment: If your method has an argument you must write `@selector(methodName:)` and if it's not just use `@selector(methodName)`!

Comment: @HamedRajabi my method hasn't an argument, I've updated the post

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It was a thread issue. I've fixed with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Timer here
});
```

Comment: Yes...I was also face this issue , i was fire this timer in background thread, after that i try with calling in main thread.

Comment: you are the hero savior! this was hard to know it didn't fire in background thread.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an NSTimer for a task of this sort. To hide your view object after a specific period of time on main thread you can use a gcd method dispatch_after

```
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * 2.0), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // Your code
  });
```

where 2.0 is an amount of seconds that will pass before the block will get executed

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(hideManual) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

**EDIT**

This code work well when `btn` (an `UIButton`) pressed and `-(void)btnPressed` function called.

```
-(void)btnPressed{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(hideManual) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)hideManual{
    NSLog(@"Hi, I'm here!");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the method to invoke is - (void)hideManual (in the same class)

Comment: What do you mean for accessible ? It is right above the line of code of the Timer. It is not declared in the header, but it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Patrick I edited my answer. This is the exact code that I'm using and works.

Comment: It is exactly the same the code I have... I don't understand what's the problem. Maybe threads ?

Comment: It was a thread issue indeed. I wasn't triggering it on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
NSTimer *manualOverlayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                              target:self
                              selector:@selector(hideManual)
                              userInfo:nil
                              repeats:YES];

repeat:YES instead of [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:manualOverlayTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code fragments it does not show when and where the `NSTimer` is fired.

if you want to use the `NSTimer`, you should fire the timer after the init, like this:

```
NSTimer *_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.f target:self selector:@selector(hideManual) userInfo:nil repeats:false];
[_timer fire];
```

but you can use the following line in your any method as well:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideManual) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.f];
```

it looks easier in this case than working with `NSTimer`.