# NSTimer not firing, has correct method signature

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using an NSTimer to call a method every second, but it doesn't work.  I can call it manually using `[refreshTimer fire];` but otherwise it doesn't work.  Any ideas why?

Here is where I initialize the timer:

```
refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0  target:self selector:@selector(sendRefreshPacket:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And then the method:

```
- (void)sendRefreshPacket: (NSTimer*) timer
{
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

Comment: Both methods in the same class?

Comment: Is the timer being run on the main thread?

Comment: Or at least a thread that runs its run loop? And in what mode is the run loop running?

Comment: I copy/pasted the code in a bare iOS app and it works.

Comment: I'm not sure which thread it's being run on... I was under the impression that using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval as opposed to timerWithTimeInterval would take care of that?

Comment: Are you using a dispatch queue to run things in the background?

Comment: If I was using a dispatch queue, what would I have to change?

Comment: You would need to add the line where you create the timer into a block that runs on the main queue. See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501186/nstimer-scheduledtimerwithtimeintervaltargetselectoruserinforepeats-doesnt) for how to do that.

Comment: `-scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` schedules the timer on the run loop *of the thread where it's invoked*. If that's a background thread that you don't control, then it probably never runs its run loop. In fact, it may be terminated after running your block. You either need to schedule the timer on the main thread's run loop or the run loop of a thread that you have created and control and in which you run the run loop explicitly.

Comment: @KenThomases how can I force the timer to be run on the main thread?

Comment: almas's answer would do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0  target:self selector:@selector(sendRefreshPacket:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            });
```